# Need for Port Forwarding VPN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, vpn, portforwarding, aws-documentdb

I'm wondering if I need port forwarding compatible Vpn given my tasks below:

Ill be connecting to aws services such as documentDB and RDS while travelling.

As a result, I plan on purchasing a dedicated IP VPN, so I can work while travelling, and add my VPN's static IP address to AWS to grant me access.

I'm working with a java spring boot backend. It connects to the documentDB and RDS and performs CRUD operations.

Does my VPN need to be port forwarding compatible?

I'm planning to purchase NordVPN with a dedicated IP, but might have to look into other VPNs port forwarding is required.

Answer (score 0):

Some AWS services are VPC only, i.e. accessible only from the same VPC network. One of those services is DocumentDB, in order to connect directly from your laptop you'll have to create an ssh tunnel and port forward.
Having said that, you could have a bastion host in AWS configured with the right access, ssh (Linux) or RDP (Windows) to it and connect from that host.

The other option is https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/